# Not able to Insert chr datatype column using RMySQL

Tags: mysql, r, rmysql

I have five columns. Out of these, am not able to insert column TagName into my database using RMySQL.
The various methods I have used are:

```
sql <- sprintf("insert into Tags (Id, TagName, Count, ExcerptPostId, WikiPostId) values (%d, '%s', %d, %d, %d);", Id, TagName, Count, ExcerptPostId, WikiPostId)
```

Output: Error in sprintf("insert into Tags (Id, TagName, Count, ExcerptPostId, WikiPostId) values (%d, '%s', %d, %d, %d);",  : 
  unsupported type

```
query <- paste("INSERT INTO Tags (Id, TagName, Count, ExcerptPostId, WikiPostId) VALUES(",Id, "," , TagName, "," ,Count, "," ,ExcerptPostId, "," , WikiPostId, ")")
```

Output: Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
  could not run statement: Unknown column 'sms' in 'field list'
Here, 'sms' is the first value of TagName column

```
dbWriteTable(con, "Tags", table)
```

Output: Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbWriteTable’ for signature ‘"MySQLConnection", "character", "matrix"’

I am using R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your second attempt

```
query <- paste("INSERT INTO Tags (Id, TagName, Count, ExcerptPostId, WikiPostId)
    VALUES(",Id, "," , TagName, "," ,Count, "," ,ExcerptPostId, "," , WikiPostId, ")")
```

You should enclose the TagName by single quotes, like this:

```
query <- paste("INSERT INTO Tags (Id, TagName, Count, ExcerptPostId, WikiPostId)
    VALUES(",Id, ",'" , TagName, "'," ,Count, "," ,ExcerptPostId, "," , WikiPostId, ")")
```

(mind the single quotes!)

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
I knew I had to put the single quotes but I wasn't able to place it in the correct place. You saved my day. Not enough rep to upvote, but will do once I get enough.